# Update data when rows equals to a pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataset looks like:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nanana | NM | RETIRED |
| Popopo | PO | RETIRED |
| Cecece | ZX | WORK |
| Lalala | AB | WORK |

And a JSON Looks Like:

```
{
"NM":"Nano Master",
"PO":"Prank Operation"
}
```

I wanted to update When
**COL A** When

> Col C = Retired AND **COL B** = Data inside JSON

If in query it might looks like:

`UPDATE TABLE SET COL_A = JSON WHERE COL_C='RETIRED' AND  COL_B = JSON->>'key'`

I wanted to achieve this using a pandas lambda function. i tried to use

```
df[COL_A] = df.apply(lambda x: "col_b" if x["COL_B"] == "RETIRED" else x["COL_A"], axis=1)
```

Comment: i mean i wanted to replace the Nanana to Nano Master from json value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={"NM":"Nano Master","PO":"Prank Operation"}

# Using np.where, check for the compound condition
# when true, return mapped value from dictionary
# else leave value as is
df['Col A']=np.where (df['Col C'].eq('RETIRED') & df['Col B'].map(d).notna(),
         df['Col B'].map(d),
         df['Col A'])
df
```

OR

```
# check for condition in mask, when true return a mapping from dict
# else leave the value as is

df['Col A']=df['Col A'].mask(df['Col C'].eq('RETIRED') & df['Col B'].map(d).notna(), df['Col B'].map(d))
df
```

```
    Col A           Col B   Col C
0   Nano Master        NM   RETIRED
1   Prank Operation    PO   RETIRED
2   Cecece             ZX   WORK
3   Lalala             AB   WORK
```

Comment: if i load json from my local, do i need to turn that into dict first? is there any option to use json? thanks

Comment: your JSON looks like a dictionary, key: value pair. is that not the case?

Comment: yes it is. the case now is that i pull my json from an API. so i think with this method i need to parse that to dict type first than apply it.

Comment: for as long as it is in dictionary, it'll work smoothly

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#load json from local,
with open('json_example.json') as json_data:
    dictt= json.load(json_data)
#or
#dictt={"NM":"Nano Master","PO":"Prank Operation"}

df['Col A']=np.where(df['Col C']=='RETIRED',df['Col B'].replace(dictt),df['Col A'])
print(df)
'''
    Col A           Col B  Col C
0   Nano Master     NM     RETIRED
1   Prank Operation PO     RETIRED
2   Cecece          ZX     WORK
3   Lalala          AB     WORK

'''
```

Comment: if i load json from my local, do i need to turn that into dict first? is there any option to use json? thanks

Comment: if you want to read local ,you should use **json.load()**. I edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df['Col A'] = df['Col A'].mask(df['Col C'].eq('RETIRED') & df['Col B'].isin(dict1.keys())).fillna(df['Col B'].map(dict1))
df

             Col A Col B    Col C
0      Nano Master    NM  RETIRED
1  Prank Operation    PO  RETIRED
2           Cecece    ZX     WORK
3           Lalala    AB     WORK
```

Data

```
dict1 = {
"NM":"Nano Master",
"PO":"Prank Operation"
}
```